# passing value from middleware to controller in restify using req.data is not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, controller, restify

project demo structure

- middleware

  - auth.js
- routes

  - user.js
- controllers

  - userController.js

auth.js

```js
exports.authUser=(req,res,next)=>{
...
//got user value somehow and it's fine
req.user=user;
return next();
}
```

user.js (route)

```js
server.get("/users",authUser,userController.userList);
}
```

userController.js (Controller)

```js
exports.userList=(req,res,next)=>{
console.log(req.user);
...
}
```

log output is `undefined`

What is the actual way of passing value in restify?

- tried restify.plugins.pre.context way too.
- tried passing value in next function.
- tried putting fucntions on [ ] as in

`server.get("/users",[authUser,userController.userList]);`

Comment: I think you should try to start with a simple case, **for example:** try running it in the same file, `middleware`, `route `and `server`, before going to a different file, do you still have the same problem when in one file or not.

Comment: For example, you can see in here: I meat it's work: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-glitter-3yq4z

Comment: Thanks for reply @TitusSutioFanpula
That still didn't worked. The project is on github https://github.com/yathomasi/opennotes/commit/ea6097c91dcc217f85a4b8fe4d0327ca1ffe8b16

Comment: terminal view is https://imgur.com/mCpBXvp
as we can see controller is running (at line 7) and middleware output is later (line 10)

Comment: The main reason why it was undefined, if seen from the image you provided, can be seen that your Controller is run first, after that your middleware.

So, your user is undefined, because your user is set in the middleware that runs after your controller.

The order of your controller and middleware:
1. Run Controller: user undefined.
2. Run Middleware: set user.

The sequence should be:
1. Run Middleware: set user
2. Run Controller: user exists.

Comment: I think I know what your problem.  I mean in your middleware, you get data from database, right? It's need a few sec, so, you have to add conditional in there, I mean if data user axists, or after select from database, then you can add next() function. If not, don't add next() function, it will get undefined. For example with my code:  https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-glitter-3yq4z  using setTimeOut.

Comment: From your code in github, you can see in the section: `routes/user.js` and in the `const validJWT` line: 64, there's next() shouldn't be there. Try to remove this next function and try again.

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula Thank you so much for your inspection and Please write these in answer section yourself because you must get the full credit.
I knew the problem was the sequence of execution but I looked for the other parts of the code trying to figure out the cause. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `data` to the `req.data` for example and if the data you add is retrieved from a database or from another service that might take time, **then make sure** you add the `next()` in the condition when the data has been received or an error.

For an example of a middleware:

```js
const myCustomMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
     UserModel.find ('...')
     .then(data => {
       // set req.data
       req.data = data;
       // next for set req.data
       next();
     }).catch(ex => {
       // next for error
       next();
     });

     // dont add the next function outside the `then and catch`,
     // next(); well make req.data 'undefined'
   }
```

For example in sandbox with timeout: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-glitter-3yq4z

I hope it can help.

Comment: I think the best way would be to use async-await and we can wait database processing to be completed first. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
user.js (route)
server.get("/users",authUser,function (req, res) {
    userController.userList(req, function (result) {
        res.send(result)
    })
})
userController.js (Controller)

exports.userList=(req,callback)=>{
   console.log(req.user);
   callback(null)
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate what is this and why to do this?

Comment: It will pass data from route to controller and the controller will send the result to the route.

Comment: The problem arose since we didn't handle the asynchronous data request to the database in the auth middleware correctly hence the controller code ran first. It's solved now. Thanks