# Unable to modified/appened REQUEST in middleware

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, typescript, express

I am new to nodejs and typescript and I want to add a new parameter in `req.body` say `req.body.jwt_token`.

**I am using a middleware** to update the request data model. **The issue is** that i am able to access (console.log works) the new key `req.body.jwt_token` just work in that function and is not accessible(don't even exist) apart from that.

I want to use `req.body.jwt_token` in some controller.

```js
export function httpsProtocol(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
        if (req.headers.authorization != undefined) {
            let authorization = req.headers.authorization;
            let authorizationArr: string[] = authorization.split('Bearer')
            if (authorizationArr[1] != undefined) {
                let jwtToken = "Bearer " + authorizationArr[1].trim();
                req.headers.Authorization = jwtToken;
                req.body.jwt_token = authorizationArr[1].trim();
                console.log(req.body.jwt_token); //able to console this
            }

        }
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            message: "something goes wrong",
            error: error
        });
    }
    next();
};
```

**Please suggest the solution** for this problem. how can i achieve this in nodejs and typescript.  I am using express as framework

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only reason why you can not access `req.body.jwt_token` in your controller is that before you set the value, you `next()`.

‍ Make sure to add your `next()` inside `if/else` condition. So, **you can copy** this code below  and use it:

```js
export function httpsProtocol(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  try {
      if (req.headers.authorization != undefined) {
          let authorization = req.headers.authorization;
          let authorizationArr: string[] = authorization.split('Bearer')
          if (authorizationArr[1] != undefined) {
              let jwtToken = "Bearer " + authorizationArr[1].trim();
              req.headers.Authorization = jwtToken;
              req.body.jwt_token = authorizationArr[1].trim();
              console.log(req.body.jwt_token); //able to console this
              // your next here
              next();
          } else {
            next(); // next or do some stuff
          }
      } else {
          next(); // next or do some stuff
      }
  } catch (error) {
      return res.status(422).json({
          message: "something goes wrong",
          error: error
      });
  }
  // next(); your next here only make your req.body.jwt_token is undefined
};
```

> Maybe this answer will help you to know the reason: [passing value from middleware to controller in restify using req.data is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59601918/passing-value-from-middleware-to-controller-in-restify-using-req-data-is-not-wor)

I hope it can help you .

Comment: Thank You, @Titus Sutio Fanpula,  Its worked for me,  I have make the complete middleware async